# Configure ASP.NET Core Router run match multiple middlewares

Tags: routes, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-routing

I am trying to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing with multiple widdlewares which can match. For example:

builder.MapRoute("api", async c => {}) // Match all api calls

builder.MapRoute("api/user", async c => {}) // Only api/user

builder.MapRoute("api/client", async c => {}) // Only api/client

But currently the only one of them can match.

If I will make MapRoute("api/{*postfix}", **handler**), then only this **handler** will run and api/client and api/user wouldn't.

Is there a way to handle multiple matches?

Answer (score 4):

Try registering a common middleware first, e.g. by using `.MapWhen(...)` and inside that middleware put your `.MapRoute(..)` child middlewares. The order in which you register your middlewares does matter and also you need to understand how "branching" works:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html

> In addition to path-based mapping, the MapWhen method supports predicate-based middleware branching, allowing separate pipelines to be constructed in a very flexible fashion. Any predicate of type Func can be used to map requests to a new branch of the pipeline.

Check out this video that explains the concept:

[image: The basics of middleware in ASP.NET Core]